# how to style bxslider border and placement

Tags: bxslider

I would like the bxslider to be centered in the browser window and have the border shrink around the photo. With the following styling I was able to tighten the border on all but the right side and I cannot center the slideshow.

I've added this style to the ul id="resort_photos" style="margin:0; padding:0"

How do I center and remove the gap on the right margin.

[image]

Comment: I use bxslider too, can you update your question with your markup and current CSS so I can see what's going on? and the Javascript in which you initialized the bxslider with the options

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('#resort_photos').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});
});

Comment: <div>
<ul id="resort_photos" style="margin:0; padding:0">
  <li><img src="climb/1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="climb/2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="climb/3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="climb/4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="climb/5.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="climb/6.jpg" /></li>  
</ul>
</div>

Comment: with a lot of trial and error I fixed this by adding <style>
.bx-wrapper {
 width:800px;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#resort_photos li img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```